# How to write request and response code with Kotlin Flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

## Problem Description

My job is very async IO heavy so a lot of what we do is requesting a value and then listening for the response. Something like

```
connection.send(GetServices(...)))
connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>()
```

Now if I did this in Kotlin with suspend functions, I could get incorrect results because the message might have been received to quickly.

```
connection.send(GetServices(...)))
// Recevied GetServiceResponse Here <---------------
connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>()
// Times out because it never got to see the response
```

However, if I flip it now I will never send the request lol. So that just straight up won't work.

```
connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>() // Timeout because we never send the request
connection.send(GetServices(...)))
```

So then you go "OK I will just launch/async" but no matter which way you do that you still have this problem that you can never be sure the listener is actually listening. There is no way to tell that a suspend function is at the point it should be and is listening.

```
val response = async { connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>() }
connection.send(GetServices(...)))
response.await()
```

This can still fail because when we call `async` it doesn't guarantee the job has ran. So the job could still be scheduled to run by the time we receive the request.

```
launch { connection.send(GetServices(...))) }
connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>()
```

This can still fail because when we call launch it could run almost immediately if there are not a lot of jobs and multiple CPUs. Meanwhile, the thread running this code could get suspended by the OS. Kotlin Coroutines are nice but the OS can still stop any thread it feels like.

To fix this, I use `UNDISPATCHED` so that I guarantee that a launch runs until it suspends.

```
val response = async(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
    connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>()
}
connection.send(GetServices(...)))
response.await()
```

This works but only in simple cases. If an engineer does something that causes a suspend before the listen then I am right back to same problem. The code above is both an example of working and not working code at the same time depending on the implementation of `connection.receive`. This gets worse when I start trying to use flows to receive data. Flow operations like merge or launchIn end up launching coroutines. So you can have coroutines launching coroutines so something like UNDISPATCHED doesn't appear to be sufficient. The only reason I know that is I actually tested it. Then again my code could be wrong.

## Question

So the question is how do I guarantee listening? It seems like I can't with Kotlin Coroutines and flows?

## Attempts

It seems like with RxJava I could, because I know when subscribe is called then it went up the entire chain. Once subscribe returns, that Observable is live. However, flows do not work like that in this regard. `collect` aka `subscribe` both suspends and eventually the flow starts listening so you have no way to know for sure.

I have thought of literally sending a "START" element on a flow to say it is live. However, you can get into the exact same situation.

```
flow {
    emit("START")
    emitAll(realFlow) 
}
```

The OS can suspend my thread between the "START" and the `emitAll(realFlow)`.

```
chanelFlow {
    launch { realFlow.collect { send(it) } }
    send("START")
}
```

Is right back to the same problem above. The job might not have run. So you launch undispatched.

```
chanelFlow {
    launch(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
        realFlow.collect { send(it) }
    }
    send("START")
}
```

But again, this is brittle. For all I know the `realFlow` has merges of it's own that are going to be scheduled and not executed. This has almost lead me back to using listeners. With a listener, I know I added them to the list of other listeners. No suspension. That seems like a huge step backwards and would make me wonder why I didn't just use RxJava.

If you got to the end. **Thank you for reading my problem.** I appreciate any attempt to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem several times as well. If the API is designed this way, there is unfortunately little you can do about it.

Just like you I ended up using `UNDISPATCHED` in simple cases where I knew one suspension point would be sufficient:

```kotlin
val response = async(start = CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) {
    connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>()
}
connection.send(GetServices(...)))
response.await()
```

When you need to make sure it can go through several suspension points, there is always the option of adding a small delay, but it's dirty, slow and doesn't 100% guarantee anything either:

```kotlin
val response = async {
    connection.receive<GetServicesResponse>()
}
delay(50)
connection.send(GetServices(...)))
response.await()
```

But honestly the best is to have a better API. For instance, in my own STOMP library [Krossbow](https://joffrey-bion.github.io/krossbow/), I have designed the `subscribe()` as `suspend` functions that return `Flow`. It might be unconventional but the API guarantees that after resuming the subscription has been made. The user can then send a request, and collect the `Flow` afterwards anyway without losing events.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. I am actually trying to write the method `sendAndReceive` lol. I went digging around in Krossbow and found that you have settled on the UNDISPATCHED solution I mention above. My question wasn't that it can't work. In my current code however, I have a two merged flows. Then, UNDISPATCHED won't help. The problem in general seems unsolvable. For example in Krossbow, I could change `waitForReceipt` and break `sendAndWaitForReceipt`. There is a hidden coupling because of the way Kotlin Coroutines work.

Comment: @DavidStocking There is definitely coupling here. When using `UNDISPATCHED` you have to be sure that going to the first suspension point is enough to ensure the subscription. This is something I'm ok to have internally (for `connect` and `sendAndWaitForReceipt`) but I totally agree this is undesirable in general. The point is to make it so that the users of the lib never have to rely on internals and don't have such coupling.

Comment: Absolutely true. I am just finding it hard when I have `merge(flow1, flow2)` to do this undispatched cause you kind of can't it seems.